# Multiple instances of a bean Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a config file in spring which I want to define a constructor parameter for each instance of a particular `@Component` that I have in spring. How can I do that?

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    public MyComponent(String config) {}
}
```

and in my `application.yml` I want to define something like this:

```
myconfig:
   - config1
   - config2
   - config3
```

I would like to make spring create one instance per config entry in the `application.yml`. Is that possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this automatically with Spring. You would have to define the beans individually probably by subclassing as @Mick suggested. Firstly, remove the @Component annotation from the base class:

```
public class MyComponent {
    public MyComponent(String config) {}
}
```

Create however many extensions of this you require as @Components for each config: e.g.:

```
@Component
public class MyComponentConfig1 extends MyComponent {

    public MyComponentConfig1(@Value("myconfig.config1") String config) {
          super(config);
    }

}
```

Where the values are injected into your constructor for you by Spring when registering the beans.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create 3 beans with one annotation? Not possible as far as I know. Why not create 3 subclasses and pull in the configuration values with @Resource annotations?
And btw: you must provide a default constructor, because that is the one being called.

Comment: Actually its going to be 14 instances of this same class. This class is a listener from a another stream system that I have no control over. So this class with the same impl has to have 14 instances and each one will listen to a different stream...

Comment: You could also do this: `@Inject Instance<MyComponent> myFactory;` After calling `myFactory.get()`, you could set your config property with a standard setter method instead of a constructor param.